# Cannot import Vue from vue in main.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, flask, vuejs2

I've got a vue MPA (multi page application) with Flask. It has two pages, index.html and about.html.
On both pages, I get the same console error in my main.js for both about and index pages.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined
    at Module.7e66 (main.js:4)
```

main.js for about.html

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import About from '@/components/about.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(About)
}).$mount('#app')
```

main.js for index.html

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Index from '@/components/index.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(Index)
}).$mount('#app')
```

My src folder structure is

```
├───dist
    ├───css
    ├───img
    ├───js
    ├───about.html
    └───index.html
├───node_modules
├───src
│   ├───assets
│   ├───components
│   │    ├───about.vue
│   │    ├───HelloWorld.vue
│   │    └───index.vue
│   │   
│   └───pages
│       ├───about
│       │ └───main.js
│       └───index
│         └───main.js
├───vue.config.js
```

If anyone can help I'd be very grateful. Thanks in advance.
I'm using vue version 4.5.11.

Comment: Did you try `import * as Vue from "vue";` ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I modified both main.js files with `import * as Vue from "vue"`, then did `npm run build` in the command terminal for my app. Now I get a new error. `main.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'productionTip' of undefined`

Comment: Make sure Vue is installed in node_modules.  And it is the correct version.  I suggest remove and install vue using npm or yarn.

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using `@vue/ cli 4.5.11` Not sure if that's the correct version? I checked my node_modules folder, and I have a vue folder inside.